# Gradle script for custom web project

Tags: java, build.gradle

I have a web project with 2 src folders. First is in businessServices >> commonServices and Second is in iSo >> src .

Now i have to write  gradle script to build this project. i want a war and jar to deploy on tomcat.. Since this is not the standard gradle project, I am unable to generate the same. Please help.

I have added the screenshots to get the idea of project structure.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-src project is not a feasible solution, U can go with multi-project build.

> Multi-project builds helps with modularization. It allows a person to
>   concentrate on one area of work in a larger project, while Gradle
>   takes care of dependencies from other parts of the project.

https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/